# Is it possible to know the geographic location where my GitHub commits come from?

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I am working on a big project (solo project) and committing to my GitHub repository almost every day. The thing is, I usually travel and my commits come from different cities/countries! Is it possible to know which geographic locations the commits came from? or at least the geographic location where the repo was created? Hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Can you use the message to populate this information?  If you (somehow) have a way of determining your location, it's possible you could script this.

Comment: Did you do a web search prior to coming here?
 https://github.com/peritus/geocommit

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not.

Commits do not track the IP from which the commit happened.  Even if they did, IP-to-geographic translations are fraught with errors.

Comment: Even further than that, there's no meaningful way for an IP to be involved in a commit - a commit is an entirely local affair.

Comment: Sure it is. Not with plain Git itself without manually saying `Location: Chicago` in the commit message, but you can do it automatically in a variety of ways with other software. Doesn’t help with past commits, though.

Comment: Although even with old commits, you can get *timezone* information.